# Do I put the function "move_uploaded_file()" on the Controller or on the Model? [CakePHP]

Tags: php, cakephp, file-upload

I want to make my own "plugin" to upload my files, cause I can't work with this (https://github.com/josegonzalez/cakephp-upload) with multiples fields and tables, so I've decided to create my own.

So, which part may I put my code? Do I need to create a behavior? Or just put on "AppModel.php" or "AppController.php" to it works? Thanks!

Sorry for the bad english.

Comment: See  this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16262194/file-upload-in-cakephp-2-3

Comment: What's the issue with Joses plugin? It contains detailed information how do to what you want including examples: https://github.com/josegonzalez/cakephp-upload/blob/master/docs/examples.rst#uploading-multiple-files

Answer (score 0):

If you want to follow MVC protocols, then the code should be in the model. If you want to share the code across the app, then either create a behavior to call on, or place the code in the appModel